# PHP get date string with leading zeros

Tags: php, string, time

I want to get the current date as a string with leading zeros, means:

```
$date = date("Y-n-j", time());
```

gives me eg: 2014-9-12, but what I want is this: 2014-**0**9-12

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php - but if you would just guess at the letters it will work.

Comment: `Y-m-d` is the format you're looking for. Literally the easiest thing to figure out even without docs

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) is a list of all the things you can do to format dates with `date()`

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
```

Comment: The second parameter is unnecessary since the author stated that he/she wants to "get the current date".

Answer (score 1):

Please read this: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

```
<?php
$date = date("Y-m-d", time());
echo $date;
?>
```

Comment: That's not necessarily helpful; the OP didn't ask for an object oriented solution to such a simple problem. If he's not familiar with OOP then it'll just be confusing.

Comment: FYI There wasn't a time component

Comment: -1 I don't know why this got 2 votes since it doesn't even directly answer the question in a helpful manner. The question itself should be closed for lack of basic research. EDIT: And now you're converting a timestamp to a date string, into a `DateTime`, and back into the `format()` function... EDIT: Now you're referencing the `DateTime->format()` function docs but using `date()`